# Differentiate result list from JQuery AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this autocomplete jquery function which displays a list devices as suggestions under a textbox. I want to identify and differentiate between all the suggestions in the list.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtLocate").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/Project/Home/Search",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          Prefix: request.term
        },
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              label: item.Device,
              value: item.Type
            };
          }))
        }
      })
    },
    messages: {
      noResults: "",
      results: function(count) {
        return count + (count == 0 ? ' result' : ' results');
      }
    }
  });
})
```

"item.Type" holds two values : Android and IOS. So I need to identify which one is Android and which is IOS in the autocomplete list. I could use different color or an image to the left of each result to differentiate. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Which autocomplete library are you using?  Or are you using your own?

Comment: jquery-ui-1.12.1.js from JqueryUI complete plugin

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories This might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use extension method `_renderItem( ul, item )` to control the rendering of menu items in autocomplete widget.

Refer the API documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem).

Refer the example [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data).

```js
$(function() {
  var devices = [
    "Ex1",
    "Ex2",
    "Ex3"
  ];

  $("#result").autocomplete({
      minLength: 1,
      source: devices
    })
    .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      return $("<li>")
        .append("<div>Image for " + item.label + "</div>")
        .append("<div>" + item.label + "</div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="result" placeholder="Start typing here">
```

Comment: Hi Vineet, hw can i use _renderItem in my example? I tried but could not get it to work.

Comment: Thnx ! this worked for me. I used .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem(...)